# 2 identities related to determinant and exponential function

Tags: matrices, analysis, smooth-manifolds, matrix-equations

This question is from my assignment in smooth manifolds and I was unable to solve this problem. I am asking it here as I think I will not be able to solve it by myself.

> Question : Let $A\in M(n, \mathbb{R})$. Prove that:

(a) $det(e^A)= e^{ tr(A)}$.

Attempt:  It is clear what $e^{tr(A)}$ means. $Det (e^A)= Det ( lim N\to \infty \sum_{k=0}^N \frac {A^k} {k!})$. But I am not able to simplify $ lim N\to \infty \sum_{k=0}^N \frac {A^k} {k!}$ and hence not able to prove what I am asked. Can you please help with that?

(b) The map $\psi : M(n,\mathbb{R}) \to GL(n,\mathbb{R}) $ defined by $\psi(B)= e^B$ is not surjective.

Attempt: The first way is to find an element of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ for which no element of $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ exists under $\psi$. But I was unable to find such an element of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

I tried another method: Assuming $\psi$ is surjective and proving it is injective, I will get a contradiction as $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is not isomorphic to $M(n , \mathbb{R})$. But I am not able to prove that it is injective. Let $e^A =e^B$. It implies that  $( lim N\to \infty \sum_{k=0}^N \frac {A^k} {k!} -\sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac {B^k} {k!})=0 $ which means that $( lim N\to \infty \sum_{k=0}^N \frac {(A-B)  (...)}  {k!})=0 $. But I am unable to see how can I prove that A=B.

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, Avenger?

Comment: @GerryMyersonn I was in bad health sorry. I am suffering from a chronic disease. Will surely reply today. Thank you for helping!

Comment: No worries. When you're up to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Av=\lambda v$, then $A^kv=\lambda^kv$, so $(\sum (A^k/k!))v=\sum(\lambda^k/k!)=e^{\lambda}$.

Since $A$ has real entries, its trace, call it $S$, is real, so $e^S$ is positive, so $\det e^A$ is positive. But the general linear group has lots of matrices with negative determinant, so the map $A\mapsto e^A$ is not surjective.

Comment: In (a), I got $Det(e^A)=Det( e^{\lambda}$, but I am not able to see how can I prove it to be equal to $e^{tr(A)}$. Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: in (b), I tried to use the definition of Det and assuming that $e^B =0$ but I am not able to proceed towards a contradiction.

Comment: My answer shows that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then it is also an eigenvector of $e^A$ with eigenvalue $e^{\lambda}$. So the determinant of $e^A$ is the product of all the $e^{\lambda}$, which is $e^S$ where $S=\sum\lambda$, which is the trace of $A$. But my remark about $e^B$ is not helpful, since the zero matrix is not in the general linear group, so I have to think about that piece a little more.

Comment: I understand and was able to complete (a) now. Thanks!

Comment: So, are we OK now that I've written up (b)?

Comment: THank you very much!